# Methods for reference date from pandas Timestamp object and datetime object?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, timestamp

I've been looking around for a method to do this but can't seem to find it. How do I get the days from reference date (epoch) from a pandas Timestamp object and additionally from a datetime object?

```
#pandas Timestamp object    
t = pd.Timestamp('2014-05-27')

#datetime object
d = datetime.datetime(2014,05,27)

#Expected output
(Timestamp('2014-05-27') - Timestamp('1970-01-01')).days
16217
```

I think the epoch is from 1970-01-01 so I would expect the output to be 16217

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pd.Timestamp(0)` to get the epoch:

```
(t - pd.Timestamp(0)).days
Out[12]: 16217

(d - datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1)).days
Out[13]: 16217
```

Comment: I was hoping for a method for this but this answer is easy enough for me